# How to get html response from a url string? (Scheme/Racket)

Tags: html, url, scheme, racket

How can I get an html response from a url string? Using this:

```
#lang racket
(require net/url)
(require net/websocket/client)
(define google (string->url "http://google.com"))

(ws-connect(struct-copy url google [scheme "ws"]))
```

Gives me `ws-connect: Invalid server handshake response. Expected #"\242\266\336\364\360\"\21~Y\347w\21L\2326\"", got #"<!DOCTYPE html>\n"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read a web page in Racket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016254/how-do-i-read-a-web-page-in-racket)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming you just want to do the equivalent of an HTTP GET.

```
(require net/url)
(define google (string->url "http://google.com"))
```

Use [`get-pure-port`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/url.html#%28def._%28%28lib._net/url..rkt%29._get-pure-port%29%29) to do HTTP GET; it returns an input port. Also, the URL above redirects, so we have to enable following redirections.

```
(define in (get-pure-port google #:redirections 5))
```

If you want the response as a single string you can use [`port->string`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/port..rkt%29._port-~3estring%29%29):

```
(define response-string (port->string in))
(close-input-port in)
```

Or you could pass it to some function that parses it as HTML or XML. There are several such libraries on [PLaneT](http://planet.racket-lang.org); I recommend [(planet neil/html-parsing:1)](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=html-parsing.plt&owner=neil).

See also [`call/input-url`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/url.html#%28def._%28%28lib._net/url..rkt%29._call/input-url%29%29), which automatically handles closing the port.